# Delphi: OpenFileDialog crashes with URL

Tags: delphi, url, uri, openfiledialog

Giving a URL to the TOpenFileDialog, the Execute method throws an exception:

```
OpenDialog1.Filename := 'http://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/app/DocRepository/1/eng/issues/terrorism/indstld_e.xls';
bResult := OpenDialog1.Execute;
```

But you are allowed to open files from a URL.

Delphi 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TOpenDialog is just a wrapper for the windows function GetOpenFileName in comdlg32.dll.

```
function TOpenDialog.Execute(ParentWnd: HWND): Boolean;
begin
  Result := DoExecute(@GetOpenFileName, ParentWnd);
end;
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927.aspx) for this function isn't that great.  But I'm pretty sure it doesn't support http.

Comment: Well holy crap. Try going to notepad and entering http://www.google.com/robots.txt in the open file dialog.